# Only safe or non null assserted kotlin message

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to run an app on mine phone and i'm keep getting this problem with my project pledase help me with this 
thank youOnly safe or non null assserted calls are allowed on a nullable receiver type of arraylis

```
register_btn.setOnClickListener { val email = 
email_registersscreen.text.toString()
   val password = password_registerscreeb.text.toString()

   Log.d("MainActiviy", "Email is:" + email)
   Log.d("MainActivity", "Password:$password")

   //Firebase Authentication  user  with email and password

   FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
       .addOnCompleteListener {
           if (!it.isSuccessful) return@addOnCompleteListener

           // else it successful
           Log.d("Main", "successfully created user with uid: 
${it.result.user.uid}")

           }
   }
```

Comment: where is your warning or error shown ?

Answer (score 1):

This issue is connected with null safety in Kotlin. As I can't really see where in your code is arrayList, I assume that you've got error in
`${it.result.user.uid}` and it should be something like `${it.result?.user?.uid}`

You can read more about it here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html

Comment: thank you  so much for taking your time to answer this question